# Spring-boot Auto-config: DataSource not getting autowired in daoimpl class, but works properly when autowired in contoller

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-boot

I am working on a REST WebService, i need to interact with a database by using a Jboss Data Source.

The problem is that when i am trying to autowire the datasource inside the DAO's impl class, it is having null.
But if I autowire the datasource on Controller, it works fine

DaoClass:

```
@Repository
public class OrderListDaoImpl implements OrderListDao{
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource; // this here gives null

     public List<OrderDTO> getOrderList(SearchOrderDto searchOrderDto,int pageSize,
             int pageNumber,String sortBy,String sortType,boolean pagination,DataSource dataSourced)
            throws Exception{
         }
}
```

My Application class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("net.colt.*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;



}
```

my controller:

```
@RestController
public class OrderSearchController {


    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource; // This gets initialized properly 

    @RequestMapping("/getOrderList")
    ResponseEntity<String> getOrderList(){
        }
}
```

I am using spring boot auto config. my application property file is :

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java\:jboss/datasources/orders_ds
server.servlet-path=/*
```

Comment: `OrderListDaoImpl` and `OrderSearchController` are in path: `@ComponentScan("net.colt.*")` ?

Comment: First your package is wrong remove the `.*`, second it cannot be null, else spring would give an exception. SO I suspect you are creating a new instance yourself in your code instead of using a spring managed instance.

Comment: @M.Deinum, i think i am getting what you mean.. let me try

Answer (score 0):

I was not creating the bean properly and which was creating a new instance for each of my class,

thanks to @M.Deinum for pointing that out.

Once I corrected the bean creating, it worked properly